# Storing Jupyter notebook "orphan" metadata in percent format scripts

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-sphinx, nbsphinx

I've got a Jupyter notebook in [percent format](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formats.html) that I'd like to add the [nbsphinx orphan property](https://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.3/orphan.html) to. Is this possible?

So far, I've tried:

1. Editing the metadata in the UI and saving (doesn't update the script)
2. Saving it as a .ipynb, editing the metadata, and converting back with `jupytext --to py:percent` (doesn't keep the metadata)
3. Manually adding a YAML header as described in the [format link](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formats.html), as follows:

```
# ---
# nbsphinx:
#   orphan: true
# ---
```

None of these seemed to work, in that sphinx is still generating a "WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree".

Comment: That warning from Sphinx means that a document whose extension is configured in your `conf.py` to be processed by Sphinx is not listed in any `toctree` directive in any other file that Sphinx processes. See docs at https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree

Comment: @StevePiercy Yes I know. The orphan directive is to disable that warning while still allowing the notebook to be linked to (without having it appear in a toc).

Comment: If the notebook metadata gets lost in translation, you should create an issue at https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try, but maybe this works:

```
# ---
# jupyter:
#   nbsphinx:
#     orphan: true
# ---
```